# How to calculate baseline hazard in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis, cox-regression, hazard

I have a Cox regression model as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(eha)

df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 sex = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"),
                 start = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 7, 0, 2, 10),
                 stop = c(1, 5, 10, 7, 18, 2, 10, 19), 
                 status = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))

  id sex start stop status
1  a   0     0    1      1
2  a   0     1    5      1
3  a   0     5   10      0
4  b   1     0    7      1
5  b   1     7   18      0
6  c   0     0    2      1
7  c   0     2   10      1
8  c   0    10   19      0

# Sex violates proportional hazards
logrank(Surv(start, stop, status), group = sex, data = df)

# Regression
fit <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, status) ~ strata(sex) + cluster(id), data = df)
```

`cluster(id)` represents the implementation of the [Anderson-Gill model](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-017-0462-x) for recurrent events. I want to estimate the (non-cumulative) hazard function from this.
I know I can obtain the cumulative baseline hazard using:

```
# Cumulative hazard
basehaz(fit)
```

But how to obtain the non-cumulative hazard? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are really two "hazard functions". One is the cumulative hazard, typically symbolized by a capital Lambda and the other is a hazard density AKA instantaneous hazard (usually a lower case lambda) which is the number of events per unit time divided by the number of time units of exposure since the prior event. In estimating these they are typically calculated at each event time. Since the last event was recorded at time 10, any data after than time would not enter into the estimate,

Comment: So there were 30 units of exposure and no effective censoring up to time 10 and 5 events. So the instantaneous hazard estimate would be (5/30) events/unit time. Its a bit different than calculating for a situation where the population at risk would be changing at the intervals between events because you set up a model where the number of cases at risk didn't decrease or increase over the course of the study. You would get a slightly different estimate with Poisson regr because the observation after the last event would be used.

Comment: And a further comment: The term "baseline hazard" would not really be applicable here. That term applies to a Cox model that has covariates, whereas you model does no have any. You might be asking for hazard density in a NULL model or "unadjusted but stratified" model. If you want the correct terminology you might first clarify this over at https://CrossValidated.com. Or maybe you want some sort of "running hazard", i.e. a Hazard (capital "H") contingent on several intermediate points? It's not actually clear as yet.

Comment: When I refer to 'baseline hazard', the model I have in mind is `Surv(start, stop, status) ~ 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `basehaz` function will return results for stratified models. Essentially it breaks the analysis into stratum-specific hazards:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                  sex = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"),
                  start = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 7, 0, 2, 10),
                  stop = c(1, 5, 10, 7, 18, 2, 10, 19), 
                  status = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
 
fit <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, status) ~ strata(sex) + cluster(id), data = df) 
basehaz(fit)
#------
  hazard time strata
1    0.5    1      0
2    1.0    2      0
3    1.5    5      0
4    2.0   10      0
5    2.0   19      0
6    1.0    7      1
7    1.0   18      1
```

Contrast that result with the results from a "null" model.

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, status) ~ 1, data = df)
basehaz(fit)
#------------
     hazard time
1 0.3333333    1
2 0.6666667    2
3 1.0000000    5
4 1.3333333    7
5 1.6666667   10
6 1.6666667   18
7 1.6666667   19
```

The results are consistent with the usual explanation that stratified model deliver a weighted average of the results in two separated strata.

Comment: How do I obtain the non-cumulative hazard from these models i.e. the instantaneous hazard?

Comment: You can calculate the piecewise “hazard density estimate” by dividing the interval difference in Survival by that interval’s duration and then dividing that result by the Survival function at the beginning of the interval and negating it. To check my memory of this basic result in the fundamentals of survival analysis you should be able to find it in the first few pages of any standard text.